# The code has errors stating 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__' and covert the bracket into an array instead of class list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack, brackets

```
from functools import reduce
import array
import numpy as np

Stack = []
StackSize = 20

arr=[]

exp=0|1|0|1
brackets = set['(()())']
arr=np.asarray(brackets)
print(type(brackets))
i=0

def push(brackets):
    Stack.push()

def pop():
 while len(Stack) > 0:
     Stack.pop()
     evaluate()

def evaluate():
    print(eval([exp[0:x] for x in range(3, len(exp) + 1, 2)]))


def main():

    #while len(exp)>0:
        for symbol in brackets:
            if symbol == '(':
                push(brackets)
            elif symbol == ')':
                 pop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am facing errors stating 'type' object has no attribute '**getitem**' and secondly I want to covert the bracket into an array instead of class list.
How can we achieve it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
brackets = set('(()())')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)